# Converting SQL query having sub query to LInQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below SQL query.

```
Select 
       a.userid,
       t.preferenceid,
       t.preferencetitle,
       t.isusercontrolled,
       value = case
                 when( a.value is not null and a.value != t.value ) then a.value else t.value
               end
From  (select 
    p.id as preferenceid,
    p.preferencetitle,
    p.isusercontrolled,
    value = case
                when( o.value is not null and o.value != p.value ) then o.value else p.value
            end
From preference as p
Left join organizationpreference as o on p.id = o.preferenceid
And o.organizationid in (select organizationid from aspnetusers where id = '101')) as t                       
Left join userpreference a on a.preferenceid = t.preferenceid and a.userid = '101'
Left join aspnetusers u on u.id = '101';
```

Now I need to convert this sql query to linq. For the subquery I have create another linq query and later I joined with other linq query. Here is the code:

```
var appUser = await _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);

var orgPreferences = await (from pf in _dbContext.Preferences.AsNoTracking()
                            join opf in _dbContext.OrganizationPreferences.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.OrganizationId == appUser.OrganizationId)
                                on pf.Id equals opf.PreferenceId into opfTemp
                            from orgPref in opfTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new Preference
                            {
                                Id = pf.Id,
                                PreferenceTitle = pf.PreferenceTitle,
                                Value = (orgPref.Value != null && orgPref.Value != pf.Value ? orgPref.Value : pf.Value)
                            }).ToListAsync();


var lists = (from orgPref in orgPreferences
             join up in _dbContext.UserPreferences.AsNoTracking() on orgPref.Id equals up.PreferenceId into upTemp
             from userPref in upTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join usr in _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.AsNoTracking() on userPref.UserId equals usr.Id into usrTemp
             from user in usrTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where user.Id == appUser.Id
             select new PreferenceDto
             {
                 UserId = userPref.UserId,
                 PreferenceId = orgPref.Id,
                 PreferenceTitle = orgPref.PreferenceTitle,
                 PreferenceValue = userPref.Value != null && userPref.Value != orgPref.Value
                                                ? Convert.ToBoolean(userPref.Value)
                                                : Convert.ToBoolean(orgPref.Value)
             }).ToList();
```

Now I would like to know if the LINQ query is right? Is there any other better way to write the query? Can you please suggest?

Comment: Do you get the same results when you run each query?

Comment: I don't really understand the point of getting `organizationid` in a subquery. Why not just join and use `where`? If that would work, then just pull out the ids and into a collection in C#. ~ `var organizationIds = _dbContext.aspnetusers.Where(x => x.id == 101).Select( x= > x.OrganizationId).ToList(); ........... var lists = .... where organizationIds.Contains(appUser.OrganizationId) ... `

Comment: Show Model classes, especially navigation propertied. LINQ query is built from classes.

Comment: Even if your Linq statement is correct you need to check the TSQL it generates. Using `.ToList()` or `.ToListAsync()' in the middle of a Linq query and then joining that List back to SQL can quite often be inefficient, as it could end up generating multiple tsql statements or pulling the whole of the joined tables into memory.

Comment: Also I don't fully understand the original TSQL query, but it would appear that the only point of the inner select is to simplify the value case statement and may not be needed. In cases like this, it is sometimes best to ignore what the original SQL says and try to understand what it is supposed to do, and as @SvyatoslavDanyliv has mentioned the Model class and navigation properties are important.